# Как создать виртуальный хост на Apache 2.2.21?

Tags: apache, windows

Искал в нете, как создать виртуальный хост и запутался - то ли просто в конце httpd.conf вставляешь контейнер VirtualHost, то ли нужно что-то мутить с httpd-vhosts.conf. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно, как создавать виртуальный хост, а то очень хочется понять, как он создается, и смысл всех директив. Если что, то у меня Win XP и Apache 2.2.21.

Answer (score 2):

Без разницы куда добавлять. Если добавляете в `httpd-vhosts.conf` тогда не забываете просто подключить его в основном файле `httpd.conf`

```
Include conf/httpd-vhost.conf
```

Затем, вы в файле `httpd-vhost.conf` пишете:

```
#если хотите управлять различными доменами на различных IP и портахNameVirtualHost IP:Port #вставляете вместо предыдущего, если не хотите заморачиваться с адресамиNameVirtualHost *:80
```

Затем самая первая директива определяет виртуальный хости по-умолчанию, т.е. такой, который будет срабатывать всякий раз, когда совпадений `ServerName` или `ServerAlias` в любом из блоков виртуальных хостов не найдено (формат у них одинаковый для всех).

Теперь сами блоки:

```
#даст доступ к основному домену, если `C:\htdocs\mysite` - корень ваших проектов#вы получите доступ к любому из них используя `http://mysite.ru/www`, например<VirtualHost *:80>    DocumentRoot "C:\htdocs\mysite" #путь к директории с файлами    ServerName mysite.ru #основное имя вашего домена    ErrorLog logs/default.error.log #лог ошибок    HostNameLookups Off #распознавать имена подключающихся хостов или нет    LogLevel debug #уровень логирования    ServerAdmin mail@host.ru #е-мэйл адрес администратора    #формат обычного лога (подробности в гугле)    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common     #использование определенного выше формата для логирования    CustomLog logs/default.access.log "common"     #здесь описаны различные директивы для директории с которой мы работаем     #(аналогично `httpd.conf`)    <Directory "C:\htdocs\mysite">         deny from all        allow from 127.0.0.1        Options -Indexes    </Directory></VirtualHost>#следующий хост даст возможность пользоваться www.mysite.ru<VirtualHost *:80>    DocumentRoot "C:\htdocs\mysite\www" #путь к директории с файлами    ServerName www.mysite.ru #основное имя вашего домена    ErrorLog logs/www.error.log #лог ошибок    HostNameLookups Off #распознавать имена подключающихся хостов или нет    LogLevel debug #уровень логирования    ServerAdmin mail@host.ru #е-мэйл адрес администратора    #формат обычного лога (подробности в гугле)    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common     #использование определенного выше формата для логирования    CustomLog logs/default.access.log "common"     #здесь описаны различные директивы для директории с которой мы работаем     #(аналогично `httpd.conf`)    <Directory "C:\htdocs\mysite">         allow from all        Options -Indexes    </Directory></VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно большое, но объясните пожалуйста поподробнее, что вы имеете ввиду, говоря "Затем самая первая директива определяет виртуальный хости по-умолчанию, т.е. такой, который будет срабатывать всякий раз, когда совпадений ServerName или ServerAlias в любом из блоков виртуальных хостов не найдено (формат у них одинаковый для всех)" - под самой первой директивой вы понимаете первый блок VirtualHost или внутри него - DocumentRoot, и как понять "который будет срабатывать всякий раз, когда совпадений ServerName или ServerAlias в любом из блоков виртуальных хостов не найдено" – т.е. я

Comment: могу ввести что угодно в адресную строку, и если это не совпадет с ServerName или ServerAlias в любом из блоков виртуальных хостов, то мне откроется этот виртуальный хост по умолчанию?

Comment: И можно пожалуйста поподробнее описать директивы директорий?

Comment: 1. У вас в каждой директиве `<VirtualHost *.80>` имеется директива `ServerName` или `ServerAlias`, когда вы вводите `www.mysite.ru` у вас срабатывает вторая директива `VirtualHost`, в которой сервер нашел совпадение в директиве `ServerName`. Т.е. если вы введете в адресную строку абракадабру, то да, вы правы, сработает самая первая директива `VirtualHost` (но для того, чтобы ввести ту самую абракадабру, ваш ДНС сервер должен знать ее, либо ваш ДНС сервер должен разрешать все виды абракадабр вашего домена).2. Описание всех директив вы запросто найдете в интернете.

Comment: искал, да не нашел

Comment: Видимо плохо искали, запрос `директивы httpd.conf <directory>` и как итог куча ссылок в [гугле](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B+httpd.conf+%3Cdirectory%3E&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), [одна](http://petrenco.com/apache.php?txt=86) из которых.